# b5paper option for book document class abnormal results

Tags: document-classes, paper-size

I'm using the `b5paper` option with `book` document class.

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage} %%added to emphasize the difference
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

However, the results are quite strange; the text body and margins are affected, but the paper size is not:

[image: with b5paper option]

This is the output without the `b5paper` option:

[image: without the b5paper option]

Comment: Simply add `\usepackage{geometry}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The paper size is set usually when you install your TeX distribution. If you didn't change it at install time, it is probably a4.

Passing the option `b5paper` to the class only changes the size of the printed part of the document, but not the paper size.

Loading the `geometry` package, the option `b5paper` is passed to it, and this package takes care of changing the paper size.

MWE

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{book}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{fullpage} %%added to emphasize the difference
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use the `geometry` package and either the documentclass option `b5paper` or that value as an option to `geometry`. The showframe and verbose options are just for checking the values/output.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{fullpage} %%added to emphasize the difference
\usepackage[showframe,b5paper,verbose]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

B5 paper has the dimensions 17.6 cm by 25.0 cm, which is seen in the verbose output:

> *geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
>   * driver: pdftex
>
> - paper: b5paper
> - layout:
> - layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
> - modes: twoside showframe
> - h-part:(L,W,R)=(60.09283pt, 350.5364pt, 90.13925pt)
> - v-part:(T,H,B)=(85.35913pt, 497.92105pt, 128.03871pt)
> - \paperwidth=500.7685pt
> - \paperheight=711.3189pt
> - (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

I skipped some of the `verbose` output.

500.7685pt --> 17.6cm

711.3189pt --> 25.0cm

The more human readable length values can be obtained by usage of the `printlen` or `xprintlen` packages.

The margins may have to be changed as well using the `lmargin,rmargin,tmargin,bmargin` options to `geometry`
[image]